# How do I write to Firebase Firestore from React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to just add a property to a Firebase document using React Native. The document already exists. Here is my code

```
import { addDoc, doc, getFirestore, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const playerGroupRef = doc(
  firestore,
  `/players_group/${playerGroupId}`
);

setDoc(playerGroupRef, {
  "test": true,
});
```

Nothing is added to the document. I have tried `updateDoc` and I get the same result. Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong? Is there something I need to check in the config. Reading the db is not an issue.

Comment: Have you encountered any errors? If so, please include it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

this is for initializing firebase, you will get your information from firebase

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "@firebase/firestore"
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
```

this for update data

```
import { doc, updateDoc} from "firebase/firestore";

async function UpdateData() {
    const dataTable = doc(db, 'players_group', playerGroupId);

    await updateDoc(dataTable, {
test: true,
})
}
```